# BGP and Inter-VRF Routing

Tags: cisco, bgp, vrf, mpls-vpn, vrf-lite

I am having trouble routing between VRFs using BGP. In my lab there is a hub router with one spoke. I am using MP-BGP to extend VRFs between the two. I want to attach a firewall to the hub with a sub-interface in each VRF. I would like the firewall to run BGP to the hub and be the exchange point between VRFs.

It seems so simple but I cant get it to work due to BGP loop prevention features. If I use iBGP the router drops routes from the firewall stating loop detected via CLUSTER_LIST (despite assigning unique router-ids and cluster-ids per VRF). If I use eBGP the router detects a loop via AS_PATH. I have gotten it to work by redistributing to an IGP and back, but that just seems silly.

I reallllly want this to work with BGP between the firewall and the router. Any suggestions? If not, what would be the next best thing?

**SPOKE**

```
ip vrf red
 rd 1:1
 route-target export 1:1
 route-target import 1:1
exit

ip vrf blue
 rd 2:2
 route-target export 2:2
 route-target import 2:2
exit

interface GigabitEthernet1
 description WAN
 ip address 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
!

interface loopback 1
 ip vrf forwarding red
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
exit

interface loopback 2
 ip vrf forwarding blue
 ip address 20.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
exit

l3vpn encapsulation ip MPLS-INT
 transport ipv4 source GigabitEthernet1

route-map region permit 10
 set ip next-hop encapsulate l3vpn MPLS-INT

 !
router bgp 65001
 bgp router-id 1.1.1.1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 remote-as 65001
 neighbor 1.1.1.2 update-source GigabitEthernet1
 !
 address-family ipv4
  neighbor 1.1.1.2 activate
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family vpnv4
  neighbor 1.1.1.2 activate
  neighbor 1.1.1.2 send-community extended
  neighbor 1.1.1.2 route-map region in
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv4 vrf red
   redistribute connected
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv4 vrf blue
  redistribute connected
 exit-address-family
```

**HUB**

```
ip vrf red
 rd 1:1
 route-target export 1:1
 route-target import 1:1
exit

ip vrf blue
 rd 2:2
 route-target export 2:2
 route-target import 2:2
exit

interface GigabitEthernet1
 description WAN
 ip address 1.1.1.2 255.255.255.0
!

interface GigabitEthernet2.1
 description FW VRF RED
 encapsulation dot1Q 1
 ip vrf forwarding red
 ip address 10.2.2.1 255.255.255.252
!

interface GigabitEthernet2.2
 description FW VRF BLUE
 encapsulation dot1Q 2
 ip vrf forwarding blue
 ip address 20.2.2.1 255.255.255.252
!

!
l3vpn encapsulation ip MPLS-INT
 transport ipv4 source GigabitEthernet1

route-map region permit 10
 set ip next-hop encapsulate l3vpn MPLS-INT

 !
router bgp 65001
 bgp router-id 1.1.1.2
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor rr peer-group
 neighbor rr remote-as 65001
 neighbor rr update-source GigabitEthernet1
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 peer-group rr
 !
 address-family ipv4
  neighbor rr route-reflector-client
  neighbor 1.1.1.1 activate
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family vpnv4
  neighbor 1.1.1.1 activate
  neighbor rr send-community extended
  neighbor rr route-reflector-client
  neighbor rr route-map region in
 exit-address-family
 !
 address-family ipv4 vrf red
   redistribute connected
   neighbor 10.2.2.2 remote-as 65001
   neighbor 10.2.2.2 update-source GigabitEthernet2.1
   neighbor 10.2.2.2 route-reflector-client
   neighbor 10.2.2.2 cluster-id 10.2.2.1
   bgp router-id 10.2.2.1
 exit-address-family

 address-family ipv4 vrf blue
   redistribute connected
   neighbor 20.2.2.2 remote-as 65001
   neighbor 20.2.2.2 update-source GigabitEthernet2.2
   neighbor 20.2.2.2 route-reflector-client
   neighbor 20.2.2.2 cluster-id 20.2.2.1
   bgp router-id 20.2.2.1
 exit-address-family
```

**"FIREWALL" (really just another router)**

```
interface GigabitEthernet2.1
 description FW VRF RED
 encapsulation dot1Q 1
 ip address 10.2.2.2 255.255.255.252
!

interface GigabitEthernet2.2
 description FW VRF BLUE
 encapsulation dot1Q 2
 ip address 20.2.2.2 255.255.255.252
!

router bgp 65001
 neighbor 10.2.2.1 remote-as 65001
 neighbor 10.2.2.1 route-reflector-client
 neighbor 20.2.2.1 remote-as 65001
 neighbor 20.2.2.1 route-reflector-client 
exit
```

Comment: Why does your Hub BGP config have its own IP address (1.1.1.2) in the neighbour statements?

Comment: Also, you have no IGP to provide routing to the BGP next-hops.  Firewall has no way of doing a recursive lookup to the BGP next-hops of 1.1.1.1

Comment: There is no need for the route-reflector-client statement on the Firewall as it it shouldn't be reflecting anything

Comment: Hey sorry, I had to type the configs from scratch b/c I dont have access to my lab right now, hopefully that is the extent of the errors. The recursion is fixed via route-maps in the lab setting the correct next hops. The neighbor statement is indeed incorrect (now corrected). The issue I am trying to solve is the BGP loop detection via CLUSTER_LIST or AS_PATH.

Comment: Have you tried using the "neighbor x.x.x.x allowas in" with eBGP?

Comment: HAH that did it! Thanks! I was surprised how difficult it was to find similar setups. Is this an unusual thing to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command

```
neighbor x.x.x.x allowas in
```

This tells the router not to discard prefixes with its own ASN in the path.